# Is There A Way to Get a Text, Obtain Words, Put them into a Function, Then Put the Resulting Words Back to the Paragraph with Pyhton?

Tags: python, text, libraries, word2vec, cpu-word

I am basically trying to replace words in a text but I need to put the most meaningful word in every sentence, put it into a function, in my case in a word2vec most_similar function, and put the most similar word in the original text. I am practically a beginner in Python so I want to find a better solution then what i do as following, which is also not working yet:

```
def closest(data, column):
    full_list = []
    datr = data[column].tolist()
    total_words = " ".join(datr).split(' ')

    # per rows
    for i in range(len(datr)):
        #first per row get the words
        word_list = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  datr[i]).split()
        print(word_list)
        #cycle per word
        total_row = []

        #for word,i in t.word_index.items(): try: embedding_vector = model.wv[word] except: print(word, 'not found')
        for i in word_list[:]:
          if len(i) <= 2:
            word_list.remove(i)


        for word in word_list:
          try:
              closest = []
              closest = word_vectors.most_similar (positive=word,topn=1)
              val = (word, closest)
              total_row.append(val)
              full_list.append(total_row)
          except:
            pass
            #print("not in vocabulary")
            closest = 0
    return full_list
```

Comment: In what way is the code not working? Does it generate an error? (If so, that error should be added to your question.) Does it do nothing? Does it do the wrong thing, and if so, in what way does it fail? Can you show its bad output on some real data, and an example of what you would consider good output instead?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.